Does a Zombuul register as dead to an Evil Twin?
The Pit-Hag turns a good player into a good-aligned Evil Twin. The Storyteller chooses the Zombuul as the other twin. The Zombuul is executed but remains alive because of their ability. Can good win now?

Yes, Good can win.
That is what "registers as dead" means. Evil Twin "sees" the Zombuul as dead, and the condition in their ability,

... Good can't win if you both live.

is not satisfied. There is no limit on Good's access to winning.
However, it does not prevent the other part of Evil Twin's ability from causing Evil to win, if the living Good-aligned Evil Twin is executed later.
